# I need some help to choose database type for my windows phone 7.5 application?

Tags: c#, xml, database

Am developing an application on windows phone 7.5, and i am not sure what kind of database that i should use !! XML,SQlite Client, or ant other type of database, my application have more than 16 table and i use c# to develop this application,i have problem in choosing the database, hope someone can help me to choose the right database type.
thx.

Comment: Is it a constraint for you going on the Internet to get your data or you want a database on your device only?

Comment: i want to develop the application on my laptop to test the application and then run the application on the phone device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) it is very easy to use.

Comment: i have difficulty in use local database,i need some help how to build the database and classes and connect them with an interface on windows phone

Answer (score 0):

In order to know which database type is more suitable for you is to know about such database.

XML is not a relational database is just a file with data xml formatted. So forget if you need 16 tables in your solution.

Besides of SQL Lite you have the choice of using SQL Server CE.  The first one is cross platform and open source, the second one is not. However I have been using SQL Server CE for a long time and I think that could fit your needs.

Cheers

Comment: my application tables have many relation, so xml is not my choose.
so i need to use SQL server and use LINQ to SQL in my application.
can you give me a website that have an real example of use this on windows phone step by step in order to start in correct way of developing because am biginner in this subject and this application is for my graduation.thx

Comment: Hi Younis, check this [link](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/21/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-getting-started.aspx) and let us know if you have any doubt or question ;-)

Comment: Hi  josemiguel,
yes i see the link that you gave me but i see in Microsoft website another thing see this link please
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626522(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: can i contact you by any kind of email of facebook,if that did not nag you

Comment: really i need your help if you can help me please

Comment: Hi Younis, don't worry. If we solve the problem here could be useful for other people. I don't understand what is actually your problem neither what you mean with "help application and add it as reference". Which are your requirements? Do you need your database to be initially populated? Please let me know...

Comment: Am working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows phone,and i want to build my application on this program ,my problem is the database i need to understand how i should deal and do and start with the database during my work and test on my laptop when i develop the solution and how to use the database when i run my application on real device.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone Mango Update (aka 7.5) introduced support for [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202872%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) as built-in persistence solution including full LINQ support and I suggest you utilize it until you have a very good reason not to.